# Meteor - Explain how the autopublish package can be so simple?

Tags: meteor

I'm looking at code inside the `.meteor` directory in my app and I decided to look at:

```
my_app/
└── .meteor/
    └── local/
        └── build/
            └── programs/
                └── client/
                    └── packages/
                        └── autopublish.js
```

I expected to find more than just 4-5 lines of code.  But all I see is the following:

```
(function () {
    /* Imports */
    var Meteor = Package.meteor.Meteor;

    /* Exports */
    if (typeof Package === 'undefined') Package = {};
    Package.autopublish = {};
})();
```

How can this package be so simple?  And where does `Package` come from in the line `var Meteor = Package.meteor.Meteor;`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The autopublish package is practically an empty package.

The livedata and accounts-base packages decide what data to publish to the client based on the presence of the autopublish package.

So no real logic is handled directly in the autopublish package, which is why it looks so simple.

If you are more interested in what is going on under the hood, browse the source code for the livedata and accounts-base packages here:

- [accounts-base](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-base)
- [livedata](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/livedata)

Comment: Thanks.  Do you happen to know which direction I might look in to figure out where "Package" is first declared?

Comment: @JonCrowell After looking around I am not to sure. I will keep looking and let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: I cannot see it being used anywhere like that in the source code, so I assume it is because you are looking at the code after it is built. From the small snippet it you have pasted, I would guess that is a global object of all the packages in the app. Where it is declared I would not know.

Comment: Thanks for your help - maybe it is a node.js thing.